# Concatenating values in each document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with documents like this :

```
{"_id" : {
        "SpId" : 250,
        "Channel_Id" : 2,
        "TweetId" : 1
},
"Sentiment" : -0.83,
"AgeGroup" : "13-17",
"Gender" : "F",
"Location" : {
        "Country" : "Russia",
        "Lat" : "46.7323875",
        "Long" : "-117.0001651",
        "City" : "Moscow"
},
"IdeaCloudText" : " PS_realized PS_have PS_enough NG_drunk"
}

{"_id" : {
        "SpId" : 250,
        "Channel_Id" : 2,
        "TweetId" : 2
},
"Sentiment" : -0.70,
"AgeGroup" : "21-40",
"Gender" : "F",
"Location" : {
        "Country" : "United States",
        "Lat" : "25.4791234",
        "Long" : "-142.0001651",
        "City" : "LA"
},
"IdeaCloudText" : " PS_good  NG_dangerous"
}
```

Though I'm apprehensive about the performance feasibility of the requirement, I have to generate an output like this :

```
{"_id" : {
        "SpId" : 250,
        "Channel_Id" : 2,
},
"IdeaCloudTextFinal" : "PS_realized PS_have PS_enough NG_drunk PS_good  NG_dangerous"
}
```

Here, the **IdeaCloudText** value of each document is concatenated in a single key **IdeaCloudTextFinal** in a single output document.

I read about the [concat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) operator but not sure if its helpful in this case(I'm skeptical that even aggregation framework is required); I attempted(of course with errors) something like this :

```
db.Twitter_Processed.aggregate({$match : { "_id.SpId":250}}, {$project : { SpId : "$_id.SpId", IdeaCloudText : "$IdeaCloudText"}}, /*HOW TO CONCATENATE*/)
```

How do I achieve this concatenation? Any performance impact pointers and/or better approaches are welcome.

Comment: use $concat http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/

Comment: How in this case would it help me - I want a single document as the output which has a key with concatenated strings as value

Comment: If `IdeaCloudText` were an array of strings, `$addToSet` might work: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet

Comment: problem is in the end he wants a string not an array of strings

Answer (score 0):

You can do `$addToSet` in the `$group` to put the strings into an array. Then, `$reduce` on the array and `$concat` them.

```
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "SpId": "$_id.SpId",
            "Channel_Id": "$_id.Channel_Id"
        },
        "IdeaCloudText": {
            "$addToSet": "$IdeaCloudText"
        }
    }
},
{
    "$addFields": {
        "IdeaCloudText": {
            "$reduce": {
                "input": "$IdeaCloudText",
                "initialValue": "",
                "in": {
                    "$concat": [
                        "$$value",
                        "$$this"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3fPbqPdD74W) for your reference.